# <audio> and Mozilla Firefox Cache issue

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, html5-audio

I have the next html code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    playSound = function(soundUrl) {
        var sound = new Audio(soundUrl);
        sound.autobuffer = false;

        sound.play();
    }
</script>

<input type="button" onclick="playSound('audioCaptcha')" value="Play"/>
```

audioCaptcha is path to my audio storage, which return the unique audio fragment. It works perfectly with Google Chrome and IE, but does not with Mozilla Firefox. Because of strange working of cache I'm getting the old audio fragment every time.
Header: "Cache-Control", "private,no-cache,no-store"

As workaround I can use soundUrl with random parameter, e.g. audioCaptcha?12345, but I hope that there are more adequate solution.

Network statistic:
[image: Network statistic]

At the next attempts no one request appear and Firefox will use the previous audio fragment. But if the user will wait ~20 second then everything is fine. Looks like that in spite of Cache-Control headers Firefox store it. I want turn off this possibility.

Comment: How is this related to Java?

Comment: @immibis I have been edited the question. Sorry for misinform.

Comment: @EugeneMironenko Showing the network request and response for the audio asset (and all the HTTP headers) might help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I submitted this issue to Firefox bug tracker and it was confirmed. 
You can track the status here: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1129121

Comment: I'm using a cache-busting query param in my stream URL as a quick-fix, like `'/stream?cache-buster=' + Date.now()` client-side (JavaScript).

Comment: @maxdec I do the same, but with Math.random() ;) Thank you for the answer.

Comment: I am having this same issue and Firefox is caching an old reference to a video file. Does anyone have a way around this?

Comment: Two years and the bug is still present. I used @maxdec cache buster to fix it.

Comment: Six years (2021) and the bug is still present, if anyone stumbles on this Mozilla's embarrassment.